# How can I disable the internet connection of an Android virtual device (emulator) using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, internet-connection

I'd like to disable the internet connection of the emulator in a fast way, e.g. by a shortcut or by extende controls for testing / debugging my app. Is that possible, because I need to switch very often between internet connection disabled / enabled?
Thx in advance for every help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Turn off by toggling this wifi button, like you do it on a real device

Comment: it also does not work for me, when I press this toggle button it shows off, but the wifi icon is still in the toolbar. when I exit and re-enter this settings page, the toggle button shows on again. so it seems pressing it has no effect

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
Settings > Wireless and Networks > Mobile Networks > Data enabled
```

check it to disable

or

```
 Setting -> Wireless & networks -> Airplane Mode -> OK
```

Comment: Thx for the quick answer. Is it also possible to disable the internet connection in "extended controls" or by a short cut? Because I need to switch for testing very often between internet connection enabled / disabled.

Comment: this does not work for me, as wifi is still enabled even in airplane mode

Answer (score 0):

When using an AVD with API level 25 or higher, the emulator provides a simulated Wi-Fi access point ("AndroidWifi"), and Android automatically connects to it.

You can disable Wi-Fi in the emulator by running the emulator with the command-line parameter -feature -Wifi.